# Symfony2 FOS Rest error pages with only in debug

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

the problem I am having is that all the error pages I configure in fos_rest only work in debug mode.

```
FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
```

The exception controller finds my custom Twig error pages from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html correctly only when debug is enabled.
When I however disable debug mode, I am getting an exception thrown in https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Controller/ExceptionController.php#L104
Twig is complaining that it's 404 even though it already figured out it's mapped.

My config:

```
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_USER
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
        include_format: false
    service:
        exception_handler:    fos_rest.view.exception_wrapper_handler
    exception:
        enabled: true
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException': 404
            'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException': 404
            'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException': 403
            'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException': 403
            'Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ServerException': 500
        codes:
        messages:
            'Symfony\Component\Translation\Exception\NotFoundResourceException': false
            'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException': true
            'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException': true
            'Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ServerException': false
    body_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: false
            html: true
        templating_formats:
            json: false
            xml: false
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - priorities: [json, html]
            - fallback_format: json
            - { path: '^/css', priorities: [ 'text/css', '*/*'], fallback_format: css, prefer_extension: true }                        
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: [ 'json', 'text/html'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: [ 'text/html', '*/*'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
```